# Replies to comments: database structure and php queries

Tags: php, mysql, comments, reply

I need to add a "replies to comments" functionality to my website using PHP and MYsql.
I have these 3 databases:

```
PAGE
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║ id      ║ content  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║ 1       ║ text     ║
║ 2       ║ text     ║ 
║ 3       ║ text     ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

```
USER
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║ id      ║ name     ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║ 1       ║ name     ║
║ 2       ║ name     ║ 
║ 3       ║ name     ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

```
COMMENTS
╔═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id      ║ user_id  ║ page_id   ║ content  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1       ║ 1        ║ 1         ║ text     ║
║ 2       ║ 2        ║ 1         ║ text     ║
║ 3       ║ 2        ║ 2         ║ text     ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

I populate various pages with a simple query (page.php?page=1 has different content from page.php?page=2):

```
$content = $db->prepare("
SELECT

p.id AS page_id,
p.content AS content

FROM `page_content` AS p

WHERE p.id = :id

");
$content->BindValue(':id', $_GET['page']);
$content->execute();
$content = $content->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and then showing results with an "echo":

```
<p><?php echo $content[0]['content']; ?></p>
```

In order to show alle the comments of the relative page, I prepare and execute the following query:

```
$comments = $db->prepare("
    SELECT

    c.id AS comment_id,
    c.user_id AS user_id,
    c.page_id AS page_id,
    c.content AS comment_content,

    u.id AS user_id,
    u.name AS user_name

    FROM `comments` AS c

    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
    ON u.id = c.user_id

    WHERE c.page_id = :id

    ");
$comments->BindValue(':id', $_GET['page']);
$comments->execute();
$comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, just using a "foreach", I can see all the relative comments and author at the bottom of the page content:

```
foreach ($comments as $value) {
   echo '<h4>' . $value['user_name'] . '</h4>' ;
   echo $value['comment_content'] . '<br/><br/>' ;
}
```

Now I need to add replies of comments, with authors too. 
I build the following database:

```
REPLIES TO COMMENTS
╔═════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id      ║ is_reply_to  ║ user_id   ║ content  ║
╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1       ║ 3            ║ 1         ║ text     ║
║ 2       ║ 2            ║ 1         ║ text     ║
║ 3       ║ 2            ║ 2         ║ text     ║
╚═════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

From here I cant go thorug my "web application" and completing it.
I cant figure how to call the query nor how group the results in the right nested order (next comment appears in list only after the replies'list of the previous comment is finished -if there are replies, of course).
I need just one level deep for the replies of the comments. Not interested about "replies of replies".

Tried other solutions I found reading other answers, but none seems working for me.

Comment: The PHP stuff isn't relevant to the problem. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How this should help me?

Comment: It describes a process. Whether you choose to engage with that process it entirely up to you.

Comment: I think u are overstimating my intelligence! :\

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt it.

Comment: I found this solution: I made a query inside the foreach, calling the REPLIES TO COMMENTS table filtered by the id of the various comments, then I join again the relative user.  Seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136485/discussion-between-matteo-corona-and-strawberry).